# Impossible to remove iMesh Search Bar from Firefox on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, imesh

I already:

- Uninstalled it in Control Panel > Add/remove programs > Imesh / Imesh bar
- Config & reset/modify my keyword URL and chose in the tools > General > Default Browser
- Re-installed it and redid the process on top

But when I type in the search address I go to http://www1.search-results.com! When I open a new tab it goes to http://search.imesh.net/?appid=393&tag=newtab!

Comment: Use `Firefox button / Help / Troubleshooting Information / Reset Firefox button`.

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox

go to

Tools->Add-ons->Extensions

Remove Imesh  from there